# Is there any way to play .MOV files in and android app using SDK?

Tags: android, quicktime

I want to play an .mov file (QuickTime Movie file) uploaded to a server via an iPhone app in the android app. It seems like .mov is not supported in Android Video Player.

So I would like to know whether there's anyway we could convert this and play on android only using android sdk without using android-ndk which looks pretty complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

MOV is not supported on Android. So maybe you need to convert the format to mp4 first.

Comment: Use ffmpeg will do I think. @furqi

Answer (score 0):

When uploading content video picked from iOS SDK we could transcode it to MPEG4 using AVFoundation framework and send to server, in my case i have done this. That will help playing video from Android Device if it needs to be compatible vise versa with iOS and Android.